# How to resize mat dialog content following the size of matdialog in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have resized my mat dialog but the content is still referring to the original size. So here's some pictures of it.

[image: MatDialog]

I searched it and they say it's resizable by using css. So i tried this.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.dialogRef.updateSize('60%', '60%');
} //MatDialogComponent Custom Size


 <mat-dialog-content class="many-inputs" style="height:fit-content; width: fit-content;">
<div class="input-container">
       <h2>{{model.name}}</h2>
</div>

<div class="input-container" *ngFor="let category of model.categories">
  <h2>{{category}}</h2>
  <h2 *ngIf="category=='System'">{{model.domains[0]}}</h2>
  <h2 *ngIf="category=='Web'">{{model.domains[1]}}</h2>
  <h2 *ngIf="category=='Mobile'">{{model.domains[2]}}</h2>
 <permissionProject-manager [data]="model" [category]="category" [customers]="data.customers" [allProjects]="data.allProjects" formControlName="permissions"></permissionProject-manager>
  
</div>
```

The size does change but it does not fit properly. Is there a way to make them fit fully following the mat dialog size? Another way is manually adjusting the width and height using the px but im worried when someone with different screen size will have a different viewing result.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your dialog by applying css class in panelClass:

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';    

constuctor(public dialog: MatDialog){}

ngOnInit() {
 this.dialog
  .open(SomeDialogComponent, {
    panelClass: ['w-11/12', 'md:w-7/12', 'xl:w-5/12', '2xl:w-3/12'],
  })
  .beforeClosed()
  .subscribe((result: string) => {}
}
```